# Kill all processes except the one running the script

Tags: process, kill

I have a aim of killing all processes (Using **killall -u myuser**) and then restart some processes.
The problem is when the script reaches **killall -u myuser** it just terminates.

How can I terminate everything (Same as **killall -u myuser**) but not the script one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think

```
killall -u myuser --ignore-case <script-name>
```

should do the trick

Comment: This is wrong. You're killing *only* the script and nothing else. It's the opposite of what OP wants.