# Kill all the other instances of a running process except the very first one

Tags: command-line, process, mplayer, kill

I am working on a project in which I need `mplayer` to run several instances in order to create voice-over-music real-time mixing from two files. So, the music is constantly playing at 90% volume (represented as "M" in the next timeline) and at certain moments we lower the volume ("m") in order to place voice ("V") over the music, after which we'll return the music to 90% when the voice sample finishes.

## TIMELINE (Minutes)

```
0===========1===========2===========3===========4===========...
_____________VVVVVVVV__________VVVVVVVVVVVVVV__________VVVVV...
MMMMMMMMMMMMMmmmmmmmmMMMMMMMMMMmmmmmmmmmmmmmmMMMMMMMMMMmmmmm...
```

Everything is working pretty fine so far. But, for some reason, many times the second `mplayer` instance finishes the voice-off playback but the process still remains active and won't ever end.

The answer provided right here: [Kill all processes except the one running the script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304918/kill-all-processes-except-the-one-running-the-script) is not working for this case.

I have also tried the accepted answer on this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50555/kill-many-instances-of-a-running-process-with-one-command but this will kill EVERY instance of `mplayer` and I need to keep the first one constantly playing music.

In this page http://www.oracleflash.com/20/How-to-kill-all-processes-with-one-command-in-Linux.html they reproduce a way to Kill all processes initiated by an application. Which is really useful for this case but this will also kill all the instances of `mplayer`.

## Expected solution

I am saving the PID of the music player with:

```
mplayer -shuffle -playlist playlist.m3u </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > player.pid
```

With that PID number, I'd like to use the last given page's solution in order to kill all the processes **EXCEPT** the one saved in the player.pid file. So, placing `cat player.pid` in the middle of

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep oraxpo | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

may do the trick.

The problem is I don't know where to place it. Or if is it there a different/better way to do it.

Another idea is to kill the last processes one at once but stopping on the very first one.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about ... `pgrep mplayer | grep -vf player.pid | xargs kill -9`?

Comment: That easy? Pfff... I need to learn that many things. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
pgrep mplayer | grep -vf player.pid | xargs kill -9
```

Notes:

- `pgrep` is *the* tool for looking up process information. It even supports negating matches and using PID files, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to selectively negate matches.
- Since you have the file, just have `grep` read from the file with `-f`, and negate matches with `-v`
- `xargs` converts input to arguments, so you don't need to use command subtitution

Comment: Seems like you might be able to use `pkill` and save the extra process.

Comment: Seems so, but `pkill` and `pgrep` are support the same features, and as I said, I couldn't figure out a way to have a single invocation do both matching on the command name and inverted matching on the process ID.

Answer (score 0):

## Easiest Tip

Just open `htop` and go to `search` and then search `mplayer` and then just click `next` and click on `kill` and its done. As simple as that.

#### Htop install command

- Fedora/Red Hat Enterprise

  `dnf install htop`
- Ubuntu/Debain

  `sudo apt install htop`
- Arch

  `sudo pacman -S htop`

Hope it works for you.

Give me a upvote if it does.

Comment: Thank you for the easiest tip. I know I didn't mention I need this for an automatic process but in the "Expected solution" you can see the details. Your "Easiest Tip" cannot be reproduced from a CRONJOB or a SCRIPT without the usage of something to manage things on screen. Thanks anyway, this issue was solved on 2016 with the solution provided by `muru` and have been working pretty fine since then. Best regards.